# Bounded density for diffusions with diffusion coefficients bounded away from $0$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, martingales

Consider a diffusion given by
$$X_t=\int_0^t a(s,X_s)\,dW_s$$
for $t\ge 0$, where $W_\cdot$ is a standard Wiener process/Brownian motion and $a$ is a smooth enough positive function bounded away from $0$.

Does then $X_1$ have a bounded pdf?

---

This [interesting answer by James Martin](https://mathoverflow.net/a/84289/36721) shows that, without assuming that $a$ is bounded away from $0$ **and** replacing $a(s,X_s)$ by $a\big(s,(X_u\colon 0\le u\le s)\big)$, it is possible that $P(X_1=0)>0$. See also comments to that answer.

Comment: When $a$ is stationary (does not depend on time) and uniformly elliptic, it is a classical result that the density of $X_1$ — the *heat kernel* at time $1$ for the corresponding second-order differential operator — satisfies the usual Gaussian bounds. The time-inhomogeneous case should also be well-known, but I do not know the references and unfortunately I do not have time now to look them up.

Comment: One more thought: another keyword might be *evolution families*. A quick google search leads to, for example, https://doi.org/10.1002/mma.5978, which seems closely related, but I did not look inside.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki : Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "yes" answer follows immediately from [Theorem 2.5 in this paper by Kusuoka](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304414916300850?token=83AF411073D65047F42CC4F378ABD1D841ADA751E9CEE4DCE66CD933F7D9311AC9D96047079D3456564E461FAA7C60B7&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20211007170037), which implies that $X_1$ has a normal-like pdf $p$, such that
$$c_1 e^{-b_1x^2}\le p(x)\le c_2 e^{-b_2x^2}$$
for all real $x$, where $c_1,b_1,c_2,b_2$ are positive real constants depending only on $\inf_{t,x} a(t,x)>0$, $\sup_{t,x} a(t,x)<\infty$, and $\sup_{t,x,y\ne x}|(a(t,x)-a(t,y)|/|x-y|<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. The local martingale $S_t = \int_{0}^t a(s, X_s) \, dW_s$ is a time changed Brownian motion, so by the Dambis-Dubins-Schwartz theorem, it can be written as a time changed Brownian motion $B_{f(t)}$, where $f(t) := \int_{0}^t a(s, X_s)^2 ds$ is the quadratic variation of $X_t$.

Assuming $a$ is bounded away from $0$ we have that $f(1) > C$ almost surely for some $C > 0$. Now since $a$ is deterministic, we have that $X_t$ and hence $f(1)$ are supported on the Wiener probability space $\Omega$ of continuous functions starting at $0$. This is a Radon space, and so we can write, by the disintegration theorem

$$\mathbb P(X_t \in U) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{f(1)^{-1}(y)} \mathbf 1_{\{B_y \in U\}} \ \, d\mu_y \ d\eta(y)$$

where $\mu_y, \eta$ is the regular conditional distribution given $f(1)$.

Since $f(1) > C$ a.s., we have that for finite measure Borel sets $U$ that $\int \mathbf 1_{\{B_y \in U\}} \, \ d\mu_y$ is uniformly $O (\mathcal \nu(U))$ as $\mathcal \nu(U)\to 0$ for all $y$ on which $\eta$ is supported. Here $\mathcal \nu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. (There is an issue here, see edit.)

Thus as $\mathcal \nu(U) \to 0$,

$$\mathbb P(X_1 \in U) = \int_{\mathbb R} O(\mathcal \nu(U)) \, d\eta = O(\mathcal \nu(U))$$

and we conclude that $X_1$ admits a density as claimed.

I think by looking at the $O(\nu(U))$ term we can show further that the density is bounded, but I have not worked out the details yet.

**Remark:** I believe this proof also shows why the case where $a$ isn’t bounded away from $0$ admits a counterexample of the form $P(X_1 = 0) > 0$. The $B_y$’s can concentrate at the origin, and so I think the absolute continuity can only ever fail at, or near $0$.

**Edit:** There is an issue with the given claim - $B_y$ is not necessarily mormal with respect to $\mu_y$ so more work has to be done here to justify the $O(\nu(U))$ claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears to me that you are conditioning the distribution of $X_1$ on $f(1)$ (I guess you wanted to write $\eta(dy)$ in place of $d\eta$). But, I think, the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $f(1)$ is not normal in general. So, you will not get the term $P(B_y\in U)$.

Comment: Yes, this is true… hmm… I have to show some kind of regularity of $\mu_y$ with respect to the usual density of $B_y$.